# Add Multiple Users to Multiple Groups in AD via csv file

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to add multiple users to multiple groups from a csv file and have looked through every post about adding multiple users to multiple groups for the past weeks but due to the nature of csv file I am having trouble executing it correctly.

The data in the csv file looks like this

```
Username,FACULTY01,FACULTY02,FACULTY03,FACULTY04
"User1,group1,group2,group3"
"User2,group1,,group3,group4"
"User3,,group2,,group4"
```

There are 20+ groups, each member can be part of 1 to 4 groups found under the faculty headings

I have the following code

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$csv = Import-csv C:\TestADGroupADD.csv -Header ('Username', 'FACULTY01', 'FACULTY02', 'FACULTY03', 'FACULTY04')

ForEach-Object {
   $username = $_.Username
   $Faculty = $_."Faculty01,FACULTY02,FACULTY03,FACULTY04"
   }

Foreach($Faculty in $csv){
   if ($Faculty -eq 'ADMINISTRATION') { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Faculty -Member $username }

   if ($Faculty -eq 'Accounting') { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group  -Member $username }

   if ($Faculty -eq 'SCIENCE') { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group  -Member $username }

   if ($Faculty -eq 'SALES') {  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupe  -Member $username }

   if ($Faculty -eq 'DEANSFUND') {  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group  -Member $username }

   }
```

I have a feeling I must use a different method to combine the faculties into one variable but I have tried with one and still fails - I am a beginner in PowerShell

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your csv format. What are the headers and how many headers do you have?

Comment: They are - Username,FACULTY01,FACULTY02,FACULTY03,FACULTY04, total 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$faculties = @("FACULTY01", "FACULTY02", "FACULTY03", "FACULTY04")
$csv = Import-csv C:\temp\test.csv -Header (@("UserName") + $faculties)

foreach ($user in $csv | Select-Object -Skip 1)
{
    foreach ($faculty in $faculties)
    {
        if ($user.$faculty)
        {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.$faculty -Member $user.UserName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mhu that looks much more precise than what I had but now I'm having a slightly different error - seems the parameter cannot be found @ line 2 "Import-Csv : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'

Comment: Sorry, forgot the brackets, see answer